# How to ignore case when using subset in R

Tags: r, subset

How to ignore case when using subset function in R?

```
eos91corr.data <- subset(test.data,select=c(c(X,Y,Z,W,T)))
```

I would like to select columns with names x,y,z,w,t. what should i do?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to find names `x,X,y,Y,z,Z,...` ?  Otherwise, why are you specifying uppercase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can live without the `subset()` function, the `tolower()` function may work:

```
dat <- data.frame(XY = 1:5, x = 1:5, mm = 1:5,
    y = 1:5, z = 1:5, w = 1:5, t = 1:5, r = 1:5)
dat[,tolower(names(dat)) %in% c("xy","x")]
```

However, this will return a `data.frame` with the columns in the order they are in the original dataset `dat`: both

```
dat[,tolower(names(dat)) %in% c("xy","x")]
```

and

```
dat[,tolower(names(dat)) %in% c("x","xy")]
```

will yield the same result, although the order of the target names has been reversed.

If you want the columns in the result to be in the order of the target vector, you need to be slightly more fancy. The two following commands both return a `data.frame` with the columns in the order of the target vector (i.e., the results will be different, with columns switched):

```
dat[,sapply(c("x","xy"),FUN=function(foo)which(foo==tolower(names(dat))))]
dat[,sapply(c("xy","x"),FUN=function(foo)which(foo==tolower(names(dat))))]
```

Comment: This works fine. I encountered another problem: how do I keep the order as I want? say dat[,tolower(names(dat)) %in% c("x","xy")]. I want to keep the column order xy,x. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: @Lin: I edited my answer to reflect both your new question and a possible way to do this. Hope this helps!

Comment: Stephan, you are truly an expert! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions with the `grep` function to ignore case when identifying column names to select. Once you have identified the desired column names, then you can pass these to `subset`.

If your data are

```
dat <- data.frame(xy = 1:5, x = 1:5, mm = 1:5, y = 1:5, z = 1:5,
  w = 1:5, t = 1:5, r = 1:5)
#   xy x mm y z w t r
# 1  1 1  1 1 1 1 1 1
# 2  2 2  2 2 2 2 2 2
# 3  3 3  3 3 3 3 3 3
# 4  4 4  4 4 4 4 4 4
# 5  5 5  5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Then

```
(selNames <- grep("^[XYZWT]$", names(dat), ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE))
# [1] "x" "y" "z" "w" "t"

subset(dat, select = selNames)
#   x y z w t
# 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 2 2 2 2 2 2
# 3 3 3 3 3 3
# 4 4 4 4 4 4
# 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

---

**EDIT** If your column names are longer than one letter, the above approach won't work too well. So assuming you can get your desired column names in a vector, you could use the following:

```
upperNames <- c("XY", "Y", "Z", "W", "T")

(grepPattern <- paste0("^", upperNames, "$", collapse = "|"))
# [1] "^XY$|^Y$|^Z$|^W$|^T$"
(selNames2 <- grep(grepPattern, names(dat), ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE))
# [1] "xy" "y"  "z"  "w"  "t" 
subset(dat, select = selNames2)
#   xy y z w t
# 1  1 1 1 1 1
# 2  2 2 2 2 2
# 3  3 3 3 3 3
# 4  4 4 4 4 4
# 5  5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: This is so neat and helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The 'stringr' library is a very neat wrapper for all of this functionality.   It has 'ignore.case' option as follows:

```
     also, you may want to consider using match not subset.
```